# Why stm32 sends invalid data by spi?

Tags: arduino, stm32, spi, embedded

Two boards: arduino nano and stmvldiscovery.
Boards are connected by spi interface. Arduino is master device. Stm32vldiscovery is slave device.
In the txBuf (transmit buffer) both board have the same data - uint8_t array (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10).

Both board send same data. Logic analyzer captured wrong data from stm32vldiscovery.
I don't know why...

Both board have spi settings:
arduino: msbfirst, freq = 1Mhz, spi_mode_0, 8 bit data;
stm32: msbfirst, cpol = 0, cpha = 0, motorola frame format, same freq;

I tried set hardware/software NSS control for stm32. It haves same result.
Same result I had with two boards - stm32f4-discovery and stm32vldiscovery. stm32vldiscovery was slave device same.

Why? What's wrong?

Yellow is arduino. Green is stm32.
[image]

stm32 code:

```
#include "main.h"
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;

uint8_t txBuff[10];
uint8_t rxBuff[10];

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void);

int main(void)
{

  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    txBuff[i] = i+1;
    rxBuff[i] = 0;
  }

  while (1)
  {
    HAL_SPI_TransmitRecieve(&hspi1, txBuff, rxBuff, 10, 10000);
  }

}
...
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_SLAVE;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_4;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

Arduino code:

```
#include <SPI.h>


void setup()
{
    SPI.begin();
}

void loop()
{
    delay(5000);
    SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
    byte arr[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        arr[i] = i + 1;

    digitalWrite(SS, LOW);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        SPI.transfer(arr[i]);

    digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
    SPI.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: As for any debugging question, you must include code sufficient to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Looks like you have your STM32 configured for a different SPI mode to the Arduino.

Comment: brhan, maybe, but why two stm32 with same configuration have same problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I replaced stm32vldiscovery board to stm32f4-discovery and it works fine!
I think problem was in stm32vldiscovery board.
Stm32vldiscovery board works badly in this mode.
I can't find nothing other reasons.
[image]